# call lambdify in a loop, avoid explicitly call

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have this code:

```
var = ['a','b','c']
arr = np.array([ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]
      ])

y = np.hsplit(arr,len(var))

newdict = {}
for idx,el in enumerate(y):
    newdict[str(var[idx])] = el

print(newdict)
```

I am splitting the array in order to have 3 new arrays, one for each variable in the `var` list.

Then , I am creating a new dictionary in order to assign to every variable the corresponding array.So, my result now is:

```
{'a': array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3]]), 'b': array([[ 4. ,  5. ,  6. ],
       [ 0.4,  0.5,  0.6]]), 'c': array([[ 7. ,  8. ,  9. ],
       [ 0.7,  0.8,  0.9]])}
```

Now, I have an expression to evaluate:

```
expr = sympify('a + b +c')
f = lambdify(var, expr, 'numpy')

result = f(newdict['a'], newdict['b'], newdict['c'])

print(result)
```

So , I am using lambdify and I am receiving the correct result:

```
[[ 12.   15.   18. ]
 [  1.2   1.5   1.8]]
```

My question is how to avoid calling explicitly `f(newdict['a'], newdict['b'], newdict['c'])`?

How can I have lambdify in a loop?

Comment: Instead of using the `for-loop`, `newdict` can also be defined by `newdict = dict(zip(var, y))`.

Comment: @unutbu:Hmm, nice!Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your particular commutative function (`a + b + c`):

```
f(*newdict.values())
```

For non-commutative functions, it's required to specify key order (as keys are unordered in a dict), e.g.:

```
f(*[v for _, v in sorted(newdict.items())])
```

With explicit keys:

```
f(*[newdict[k] for k in 'abc'])
```

Using `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
newdict = OrderedDict()
for idx,el in enumerate(y):
    newdict[str(var[idx])] = el

f(*newdict.values())
```

(`f(*[1, 2, 3])` is equivalent to `f(1, 2, 3)`.)

Comment: You can also write `f = lambdify((var,), expr, 'numpy')` and call it like `f(args)` (without the `*`).

Comment: @asmeurer:
 
Can I ask you something?If I have this dict new_dict = {'a': np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 'b': np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])} and use print(f([v for v in sorted(new_dict.items())])), it gives me: TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational.Any ideas? Thanks!(I am sending both the comment)

Comment: You cannot sort SymPy objects directly. You need to pass a sort key to sorted (one option is `key=sympy.default_sort_key`).