# cannot determine truth value of Relational when applying lamdbdify

Tags: python, sympy

This is kind of continuation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528763/call-lambdify-in-a-loop-avoid-explicitly-call).

I have this code:

```
import sympy
import numpy as np
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

arr = [np.array([ 1, 2,3 ,4]), np.array([ 5, 6, 7, 8])]
a,b = sympy.symbols('a b')
var = [a,b]
expr = 'a+b'
new_dict = dict(zip(var, arr))
print(new_dict)
```

which gives me:

`{a: array([1, 2, 3, 4]), b: array([5, 6, 7, 8])}`

Then , I use lambdify:

`f = lambdify( var, expr, 'numpy')`

If I try to apply `f`:

```
print(f([v for _,v in sorted(new_dict.items())]))
```

I am receiving:

```
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

According to comments in previous question, I have to use the `default_key` but I am not sure how to properly use it.

If I try something like:

```
n = sorted(new_dict.keys(),  key=sympy.default_sort_key)

for k,v in zip(n,new_dict.values()):
    print(f(v))
```

I am receiving:

```
<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: '_Dummy_21'
```

when I call `print(f(v))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) to map the two *lists* into an ordered *dictionary* which combines them in the same order as they appear. Then, unpack the arguments which constitute the *dictionary's* values for the function call as shown:

```
import sympy
from sympy import sympify
import numpy as np
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
from collections import OrderedDict


arr = [np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([5,6,7,8])]
a,b = sympy.symbols('a b')
var = [a,b]
expr = a+b                  # Alternatively, use sympify to convert the expression 
                            # that can be understood by Sympy, expr = sympify("a+b") 
f = lambdify(var, expr, "numpy")
vals = OrderedDict(zip(var, arr)).values()
f(*vals)
#array([ 6,  8, 10, 12])
```

Note that `a` and `b` are still of type `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol` and not `str` and hence the `sorted` method can't be applied directly to the *dictionary* keys.

Comment: Hi, I opened a new post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42614281/map-each-element-to-expression) which is similar to this.If you can help,thanks!