# map each element to expression

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have this code:

```
import sympy
import numpy as np
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
from collections import OrderedDict

arr = [np.array([ 1, 2]), np.array([ 5, 6])]
a,b = sympy.symbols('a b')
var = [a,b]
expr = ['a+cos(b)', 'a+cos(b)*2']

f = lambdify( var, expr, 'numpy')

vals = OrderedDict(zip(var, arr)).values()
f(*vals)
```

and I am receiving:

```
[array([ 1.28366219,  2.96017029]), array([ 1.56732437,  3.92034057])]
```

I want to receive:

```
[array([ 1.28366219,  3.92034057])]
```

hence :

`1+np.cos(5) = 1.28366219`

`2 +np.cos(6)*2 = 3.92034057`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the way you implemented `f`, I think the only way to get your desired output is to access the desired elements directly. When you pass values for `a` and `b`, both expressions in `f` will be evaluated and returned in a list (as you defined it). You can check `f.func_doc`

```
f.func_doc
"Created with lambdify. Signature:\n\nfunc(a, b)\n\nExpression:\n\n['a+cos(b)', 'a+cos(b)*2']"
```

Then

```
f(1, np.pi)
```

returns

```
[0.0, -1.0]
```

as expected, where `0.0` corresponds to `a+cos(b)` and `-1.0` to `a+cos(b)*2`.

In your example you could simply do:

```
[vali[i] for i, vali in enumerate(f(*vals))]
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
[1.2836621854632262, 3.9203405733007317]
```

I guess it would be easier to define the expressions separately rather than in a list as you currently do it but I don't know the reason for the structure you chose:

```
from sympy import cos

f1 = lambdify((a, b), a+cos(b))
f2 = lambdify((a, b), a+cos(b)*2)

res = [np.array([f1(1, 5), f2(2, 6)])]
```

which gives

```
[array([ 1.28366219,  3.92034057])]
```