# TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational with dict(zip()), only with direct output

Tags: python, dictionary, sympy, python-zip

**EDIT**:
The problem only appears when trying to get "direct output" of the result of `dict(zip(...`.
This code, with output via `print`, works fine

```
import sympy as sp
x, y = sp.symbols('x,y')
d = dict(zip([x, y], [1, 1]))
print(d)
```

but simply entering `dict(zip([x, y], [1, 1]))` throws the error.

---

Code as simple as this

```
import sympy as sp
x, y = sp.symbols('x,y')
dict(zip([x, y], [1, 1]))
```

Produces error

```
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Why, and how can I solve this?
If not using `OrderedDict`, that would be most convenient.

It seems [this OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609884/cannot-determine-truth-value-of-relational-when-applying-lamdbdify) has no problem in doing what is giving me the error (it has a different problem).

Full code, etc. I know it's an old python version, but I guessed it should work.

```
>>> x, y = sp.symbols('x,y')
>>> dict(zip([x, y], [1, 2]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 449, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 692, in pphook
  File "C:\development\Portable Python 3.6.5 x64 R2\App\Python\lib\pprint.py", line 53, in pprint
    printer.pprint(object)
  File "C:\development\Portable Python 3.6.5 x64 R2\App\Python\lib\pprint.py", line 139, in pprint
    self._format(object, self._stream, 0, 0, {}, 0)
  File "C:\development\Portable Python 3.6.5 x64 R2\App\Python\lib\pprint.py", line 161, in _format
    rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
  File "C:\development\Portable Python 3.6.5 x64 R2\App\Python\lib\pprint.py", line 393, in _repr
    self._depth, level)
  File "C:\development\Portable Python 3.6.5 x64 R2\App\Python\lib\pprint.py", line 405, in format
    return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level)
  File "C:\development\Portable Python 3.6.5 x64 R2\App\Python\lib\pprint.py", line 511, in _safe_repr
    items = sorted(object.items(), key=_safe_tuple)
  File "C:\development\Portable Python 3.6.5 x64 R2\App\Python\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py", line 384, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you provide more information about what versions you're using?

Comment: @Unmitigated - New findings posted, which change the game.

Comment: So creating the dict works fine, but displaying it gives problems?  Does the `print(d)` work?  `print` uses the `str(d)` display, while the interactive display uses `repr(d)`.  It also uses your `pprint`, as shown by the traceback.  I'm not familiar with `R2\App\Python\lib\pprint.py"`

Comment: Does this pprint have problems with other sympy expressions?, e.g. just the symbol `x`, or some expression like `x/y`?

Comment: Where are you calling `pprint()`? You need to use `sort_dicts=False` so it doesn't try to sort the dictionaries. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter

Comment: @hpaulj - Yes, as stated, `print(d)` works fine. 
`print()` <-> `str()` and Interactive <-> `repr`/`pprint` is likely part of the cause.

Comment: @hpaulj - Does `pprint` have other problems? 
This is the first time I find one. No problems with `x` or `x/y`. 
It is probably the combination with some particular `dict`s, see comment by Barmar.

Comment: @Barmar - I am not calling `pprint` explicitly.
It is likely behind the Interactive display, see exchange with hpaulj.
My `pprint` (<3.7) does not have `sort_dicts`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683088/disabling-sorting-mechanism-in-pprint-output.
I guess the "Why...?" part of the OP is answered. 
For the "How to...?" I will have to dig a little further.

Comment: @hpaulj - Will shortly remove the comments at the beginning, to reduce the clutter.

Comment: @Barmar - Will shortly remove the comments at the beginning, to reduce the clutter.

Comment: What interactive environment are you using that automatically calls `pprint()`? Check whether there's a way to make it print normally.

Answer (score 2):

In an upto date sympy environment (`ipthon` with `isympy`) I can display a `dict` with symbols either with the `repr` or str (the print is easier to copy-n-paste):

```
In [70]: print(d)
{x: 1, y: 1}
```

But if I try to sort the dict, I get your error:

```
In [71]: sorted(d)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[71], line 1
----> 1 sorted(d)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py:511, in Relational.__bool__(self)
    510 def __bool__(self):
--> 511     raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Using the standard `pprint` also invokes this sorting and error:

```
In [72]: import pprint
In [73]: pprint.pprint(d)
```

but turning off the sorting

```
In [74]: pprint.pprint(d, sort_dicts=False)
{x: 1, y: 1}
```

The problem is that sorting needs to determine an ascending order.  That's impossible for symbols.  `x>y` is a `Relational`, that doesn't have have clean boolean value:

```
In [80]: bool(x>y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[80], line 1
----> 1 bool(x>y)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py:511, in Relational.__bool__(self)
    510 def __bool__(self):
--> 511     raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

The topic of dict sorting came up recently in a SO about `[argparse]`.  Its `args` `Namespace` object used to sort its attributes on display, but that sorting was removed in 2020.  A core developer speculated that in old Python dicts, the keys were presented in an non-determinant order ("random"), so sort was often desirable.  But now `dict` preserves the order in which keys are first assigned.  The user has more control over the display order, and doesn't need the sorting (as often).  The sorting in `pprint` probably has the same roots.